# How to check if dovecot's configuration is valid? (config file syntax)

Tags: email-server, configuration, dovecot

Is there a command that I can issue that will tell me if the current set of config files for dovecot are valid or if there's an issue?

I just made a change to my dovecot config files. Before attempting to restart the service, I just want to do a quick sanity check to confirm if I made a fat-finger mistake or not.

I'm looking for the dovecot equivalent of any of the following:

```
nginx -t
apachectl -t
postfix check
```

Please let me know if there is some way to check the validity of my dovecot configuration.

Answer (score 12):

Use `doveconf`.

The below `doveconf` command will exit non-zero and output a message if there's an issue with your dovecot config

```
doveconf 1>/dev/null
echo $?
```

The above command will output only STDERR and the print the exit status of `doveconf`.

For example, the following output confirms that the dovecot config is OK.

```
root@host:~# doveconf 1>/dev/null
root@host:~# echo $?
0
root@host:~#
```

Comment: `alias doveconfchk='doveconf >/dev/null && echo OK'`